# Android Studio keeps crashing cause of gradle (?)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I wanted to create a scrollable layout with lots of Textviews. I did it but when i started putting in TextViews I noticed the program started getting really laggy. So I kept adding TextViews on but on the blueprint caused on that it worked just fine. So when I finished adding TextViews (272 to be exact) I went over to the normal Design menu and Android Studio just completely crashed. It shows this message: there is not enough memory to perform the requested operation. please increase xmx setting. So I gave Android studio more Ram memory (8 GB) but whenever I enter the normal design it crashes, blueprint design works just fine though. I really don't know why this is but my 2 best guesses are that 1. 272 is too many textViews for the program to handle or 2. I implemented the scrollview layout wrong.

Edit: Didn't realize at the time creating so many TextViews was in detriment of performance. Created a listView instead and fixed the issues.

Comment: Why 272 textviews? Why not a `ListView` where each list item has a `TextView`?

Comment: Don't know how to do this...

Comment: I'm knew to programming.

Comment: 272 ?? use ListView google how to create a ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use ListView?

here is what you want:
http://abhiandroid.com/ui/listview